# How to change default styling of browser?

Tags: css

Look at this

[image]

I'm using FireFox. This is when the browser has saved the login credentials. Inputs actually have values but it can not be seen cause the colors are the same with the background. This is the default style of browser for saved inputs. In my styles, inputs are dark. Not this yellowish bright. It totally ruins the design.

How can I change it? I mean I don't want it to look like that when a user saves their credentials in a browser.

Is there a way for that?

P.S: I'm not expert in frontend development. Thanks.

Comment: Do these textboxes already have a style? Can we see it?

Comment: Yeah I edited the post. They are dark in my styles.

Comment: However, I should note that it makes sense for the user to **easily recognize** when login credentials are being auto-filled. So, I would think twice before shipping this style override.

Comment: @Lae yes it's the case. Thanks.